# Simple way of making an SVG block in React have a gradient of color using D3.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I,m trying to create a bar chart in a React component using D3.js, but can't seem to find simple instructions to create a rectangle that starts with a solid color at one end and fades away towards the other end.

So given a simple 30 x 300 rect:

```
const bar = () => {
  const b = select('svg')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', 300)
    .attr('height', 30)
}

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    bar()
  })
    return (
      <div>
        <svg width={200} height={200}>

        </svg>
      </div>
    )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

How do I make the block fade from solid black to grey?

Comment: check out [this resource in d3](http://bl.ocks.org/pnavarrc/20950640812489f13246) or [this resource in plain svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients)

Answer (score 0):

You can use liner gradients with defs for that purpose.
here is the detailed article for your reference.
[D3 Charts with Gradient Color](https://dev.to/chooblarin/d3js-chart-with-gradient-color-4j71)